# What is the flower just above the groom's left breast?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have this image

[image]

I am wondering what the flower is that's just above the groom's left breast (her left) and if the greenery with it is native to the flower (ie. if you cultivated the flower or found it in the wild, you'd see that greenery)

I'm also curious of the other flowers as at the moment i'm assuming the bride has roses on her dress and veil and the bouquet is made us of the same flower as what the groom has but i'm fine in just knowing the groom's flower

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a plant in a fictional universe.

Comment: See the discussion on meta: [**Are questions about cartoons on-topic?**](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/513/are-questions-about-cartoons-on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

I'll take a guesstimate by making some cultural assumptions seeing as this is not a picture of a real flower but an artist's rendering.

The [madonna lily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilium_candidum) is claimed to be one of the oldest garden flowers from the Mediterranean area.

> In the early days of Christianity it was dedicated by the Church to
> the Madonna (hence its popular name), probably because its delicate
> whiteness was considered a symbol of purity. It is employed on the 2nd
> July, in connection with the celebration of the Visitation of the
> Blessed Virgin[2](https://www.botanical.com/botanical/mgmh/l/lilmad24.html)

[image: madonna lily courtesy of wikimedia.org]

I don't know what the other small flowers in the bouquet are.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Kevinsky, the Madonna lily is probably the model for this stylized flower - but in practice, you'd never use any kind of Lilium flower in a buttonhole unless you'd removed the pollen bearing stamens (unlikely anyone would bother) because the pollen stains clothing. If you look closely, the flowers in the bride's bouquet cannot be the same as the groom's flower because they have six petals, and the groom's only five, so botanically (if this were actually real and not an imagined flower) they wouldn't be the same flower.

Comment: Nice, you looked much more carefully than I did!

Comment: @kevinsky just picky, and got new specs!

Comment: Clovers have sometimes 3 and sometimes 4 petal like parts presumably in the same species.